# Attribute Filter Not Working After Importing Product

Tags: magento

When i am import product than attribute of product saved as a catalog_attribute_entity_text and this is not filterable but when i saved again product from admin than that attribute will move to catalog_attribute_entity_int.

After this layered filter is working. But my product is lots so how to move attribute catalog_product_entity_text to catalog_product_entity_int and is there any way to achieved this one.

Comment: Try to use magmi to Import products.

Comment: product is already uploaded is that any other way.

Answer (score 0):

After import product run a core Sql Query.

```
insert into catalog_product_entity_int (entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value) select entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id = '81';
```

Replaced your attribute id to this 
Run your SQL Query via direct sql or via magento.
Thanks